# How to access a specific metric from a consumer in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, jmx

i am working with a java producer and consumer, i am trying to visualize my consumer lag (i have it lagging in purpose) from my java application. I want to log that lag as a stdout. I have tried to use JMX but i havent been able to use it in the java application.
I have used this (just a snippet, the set up of the consumer is done in the application)

```
private KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer

Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric> metrics = consumer.metrics();
System.out.println(metrics);
```

But it only gives me the description of the metrics but not the value.
I see in my Kafka CLI and it shows the right lag for that consumer.

Comment: all the metrics are published via jmx.Take a look: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html

Comment: i tried to accesing them, but i couldnt get them in my java app. Do you have a snippet that log metrics using jmx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First identify which metrics you are interested in using the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) or printing all metrics like in your question.

Then find the metrics from the Consumer. For example, if you are interested in `request-latency-avg`:

```java
// Find the metrics you are interested in
Metric requestLatencyAvgMetric = null;
for (Entry<MetricName, ? extends Metric> entry : consumer.metrics().entrySet()) {
    if ("request-latency-avg".equals(entry.getKey().name())) {
        requestLatencyAvgMetric = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the value when you need it using:

```java
requestLatencyAvgMetric.metricValue()
```

Comment: When i output it, it says NaN. To see the whole metric i output just the object metric and i got this. org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric@6e162f78
The lags shows in the console consumer group description but it doesnt in the program